# Right algorithm for grouping food items and ingredients?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**Problem**

Given N food items each containing a set of ingredients. There are a pool of M ingredients.

A group is formed consisting of food items and ingredients such that each of the food item in that group contains all of the ingredients in that group.

The problem is to create the groups using the foods and ingredients such that each ingredient and a food item is covered(There should be a group present corresponding to each mapping of food item and ingredient) with the constraint of minimising the number of groups created.

---

**Example:**

**Input**

N = 3, M = 3

Ingredients('a', 'b', 'c')

Food Item 1 containing ('a', 'b', 'c') ingredients.

Food Item 2 containing ('b', 'a') ingredients.

Food Item 3 containing ('a', 'b', 'c') ingredients.

**Output**

2 groups

**Group 1:** (Food Item 1, Food Item 2, Food Item 3)('a', 'b')

**Group 2:** (Food Item 1, Food Item 2)('c')

---

The solution that I thought of is to compute all subsequences of the ingredients, assign them to groups and add the appropriate food items in the group. But, this doesn't seem to be the right algorithm.

Comment: What about it "seems" wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question?

Comment: One group contains all food items and all ingredients. What is wrong with this solution?

Comment: Suppose, Food Item 1 contains ('a', 'b') and Food Item 2 contains ('b', 'c'). If we try to create one group of (Food Item 1, Food Item 2)('a', 'b', 'c'). This is wrong because Food Item 1 does not contain ingredient 'c' and Food Item 2 does not contain ingredient 'a'.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can help with this, but it's not clear in your question what is "minimizing" for you and also what "..is covered" means for you.

In you example, if you considered only the first 2 groups that is

Food Item 1

Food Item 2

it seems that all food items are covered, and also all the ingredients , 'a'+'b' being in the first group and 'c' being in the second group. What am I missing here that you added the third group?

Thanks,

Comment: Ingredient 'b' is also part of the Food Item 2. So, there should be a group with the food item 2 and ingredient 'b'.

Comment: ok, you should be more specific. Indeed if you take only the first 2 groups there IS a group with food Item 2 and ingredient 'b', it's the one element group  [Food Item 2], that is the second group.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you were right. I have changed the example now.

Comment: I've just signed up to stack overflow, If my asnwerd was good to clarified the question, can you up-vote it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be:

1. create a Group for every single ingredient.
2. put in these groups all Food items that contain that ingredient.
3. check if two different Groups contain the same Food items, join them together.
4. repeat until there are no two Groups that contain exactly same Food items.